# put anchor and li with same size

Tags: html, css

I need to put a anchor inside my li, using the same space as if it was just one element. Actually, I want to build this screen: http://postimage.org/image/w2q9ei21r/
I already have a code I just started, but I had some problems because the anchor is not occuping the same space of li. I appreciate any help.
http://jsfiddle.net/Br9Km/2/

Comment: I'm changing the background color. Instead to put on <li> i'm putting on the anchor. I already have one menu that worked in this way.

Comment: I'm almost there in this new way: http://jsfiddle.net/Br9Km/26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what's being presented on your image with this structure:

- See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfB95/) example for having the visitor **clicking
  over the month name**!

  *On this print-screen, you can see the mouse over the "Fevereiro" month.*

  [image: Menu Print Screen]

**CSS**

```
/* rounded corners */
#ConteudoMeses li, #ConteudoMeses li a, #ConteudoMeses li span {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    behavior: url(/Themes/Default/Scripts/PIE.htc);
}

/* LI element format */
#ConteudoMeses li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 76px;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}

/* link format */
#ConteudoMeses li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 74px;
    width: 110px;
    color: white;
}

/* arrow holder format */
#ConteudoMeses li span {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    height: 74px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

---

- See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfB95/2/) example for having the visitor **clicking
  on the month name and correspondent arrow**!

  *On this print-screen, you can see the mouse over the "Fevereiro" month.*

  [image: Menu Print Screen]

**CSS**

```
#ConteudoMeses li, #ConteudoMeses li a, #ConteudoMeses li span {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    behavior: url(/Themes/Default/Scripts/PIE.htc);
}
#ConteudoMeses li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 76px;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}

#ConteudoMeses li a {
    display: block;
}
#ConteudoMeses li .label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 74px;
    width: 110px;
    color: white;
}

#ConteudoMeses .arrow {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    height: 74px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, why do you used the span label to put the month name? Why not using just the anchor element for this?

Comment: Because you have to different background colors, one for the month name and another for the arrow :) And for that you need distinct elements to apply the background colors! The `a` tag is a wrapper of those elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `<a>` tag style to `display:block`.

Block elements, like `li` or `div` will fill the whole available width by default. Then you could also set the `height` of `<a>` tag to fill in the height properly.